# What is meaning of .// in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

I know absolute XPath will return the inspected node from root node in XML tree.

But I am not able to understand the meaning of `.//` used in XPath to inspect/find a node.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`.` is the current node; it is short for `self::node()`.

`//` is the descendant-or-self axis; it is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`.

Together, `.//` will select along the descendent-or-self axis starting from the current node.  Contrast this with `//` which starts at the document root.

### Example

Consider the following HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="id1">
      <p>First paragraph</p>
      <div>
        <p>Second paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Third paragraph</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**`//p` will select all paragraphs:**

```
      <p>First paragraph</p>
      <p>Second paragraph</p>
      <p>Third paragraph</p>
```

On the other hand, if the current node is at the `div` element (with `@id` of `"id1"`), then **`.//p` will select only the paragraphs under the current node**:

```
      <p>First paragraph</p>
      <p>Second paragraph</p>
```

Notice that the third paragraph is not selected by `.//p` when the current node is the `id1` `div` because the third paragraph is not under that `div` element.