# How to get different tables from one page using Python (lxml, html, requests, xpath)?

Tags: python, html, python-requests, lxml

I am trying to get the data of Premier League table from https://www.premierleague.com/tables . I am able to get the data through the code below, but unfortunately it only works for the latest season option (*2018/2019*). The page offers tables for other seasons as well (*2017/2018, ...)*, **how can I scrape the other tables?**

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.premierleague.com/tables')

tree = html.fromstring( page.content )

team_rows = tree.xpath('//table//tbody//tr[@data-filtered-table-row-name]')[0:20]
team_names = [i.attrib['data-filtered-table-row-name'] for i in team_rows] 

teams = {}

for i in range(20):
    element = team_rows[i]
    teams[team_names[i]] = element.getchildren()

for i in team_names:
    values = [j.text_content() for j in teams[i]]
    row = "{} "*9
    print( row.format(i, *values[3:12] ) )
```

Comment: Open that page in chrome and then open your Network tab. Now when you change the season you can see what request chrome makes to get that data.

Comment: the requests are from `https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/standings`, but I don't get the reason why can include that..and also for the `params`, and `headers` parameters for `requests.get`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but unfortunately it only works for the latest season option (2018/2019)

Website is using JavaScript to load the old table(1992-2017), so when you use Python to access that you gain latest table. If you desire to scrape the table filter by year/session, i provide a hard code version for you(Because i did not found the rule of year number). But you want to complete it more elegantly, selenium or requests_html might suit for you.

Note: **Im imitating JavaScript gain data from server, so the response's content is json type. And it can only gain different year's Premier League table.** Filter by competition/matchweek/home_or_away is not available in my example. If you want to add those option into script, you should analysis the rule of url parameter(use the way @pguardiario said or use some tools like fiddler).

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

years = {str(1991+i):str(i) for i in range(1,23)}
years.update({
    "2018":"210",
    "2017":"79",
    "2016":"54",
    "2015":"42",
    "2014":"27"
    })

specific = years.get("2017")

param = {
    "altIds":"true",
    "compSeasons":specific,
    "detail":2,
    "FOOTBALL_COMPETITION":1
}

headers = {
    "Origin": "https://www.premierleague.com",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36",
    "Referer": "https://www.premierleague.com/tables?co=1&se={}&ha=-1".format(specific),
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
    }

page = requests.get('https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/standings',
                 params=param,
                 headers=headers
                 )
print(page.url)
pprint(page.json())
```

> How to get different tables from one page

I feel your question title is different from you description. If it is true, The other issue is you combine all table into one. And you should be care of `//` [What is meaning of .// in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31375091/what-is-meaning-of-in-xpath).

Note: ***If you want to get old data of Premier League table, use my code in 1st part.*** Because those data can only be gotten from that way.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
from pprint import pprint

years = {str(1991+i):str(i) for i in range(1,23)}
years.update({
    "2018":"210",
    "2017":"79",
    "2016":"54",
    "2015":"42",
    "2014":"27"
    })

param = {
    "co":"1",
    "se":years.get("2017"),
    "ha":"-1"
}


page = requests.get('https://www.premierleague.com/tables', params=param)

tree = html.fromstring( page.content )
tables = tree.xpath('//tbody[contains(@class,"tableBodyContainer")]')
each_table_team_rows = [table.xpath('tr[@data-filtered-table-row-name]') for table in tables]
team_names = [[i.attrib['data-filtered-table-row-name'] for i in team_rows] for team_rows in each_table_team_rows]

pprint(team_names)
```

Comment: Using the `requests.get('https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/standings',
                 params=param,
                 headers=headers
                 )` works, but using param = `{'co': '1', 'se': '21', 'ha': '-1}` still returns when `se=21` (which is the default season). The 2nd answer does not work, I also followed that from http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request

Comment: When i modified first part i forget to edit second part, *apart from latest season you need to use my 1st example to gain it.* actually, my 2nd part is to answer your title question, because  your question title looks like asking another question.

Comment: Why my 2nd part code doesn't work, because the actual way to get match data is through the url in my 1st part.

Comment: The 2nd part only results the default table, regardless the value of `'se'`.. (which means it does not work to solve the problem) If it is only to get the default, then other years are not needed..

Comment: Yes, my 2nd part just show how to extract data with `XPAHT`. *If you want to get data you have to used my 1st part.* Because it is the website decide it.  Of course, *if you insist using XPATH you have to use `selenium`*, since i have tried to use requests_html and got unexpected result.

Comment: I see `'footballapi.pulselive.com/football/competitions?page=0&pageSize=100&detail=2'` in the Chrome, instead of `'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/standings'`.. Although, both worked

Comment: It's great news, but table's data you want is inside `/football/standings`