# Difference between //, .//, and ..// in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, robotframework

Can anyone please help with the difference between the below XPaths and help me understand which of these to use when. I have found all three of them to work but not sure when to use them.

1. `Get Element Text     ${output}       //priority`
2. `Get Element Text     ${output}      .//vrrp-group/name`
3. `Get Element Text     ${output}      ..//track/priority-hold-time`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Difference between //, .//, and ..// in XPath in general

`//` selects among descendant or self nodes (along the [`descendant-or-self` axis](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html#Get%20Element%20Text)).  It is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`.

1. `//` starts from the root node, thus covering the entire document.
2. `.//` starts from the [context node](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1022354/290085).
3. `..//` starts from the parent of the context node.

### In your particular case

1. `//priority` selects all `priority` elements in the document.
2. `.//vrrp-group/name` selects, beneath the context node, all `name` elements  with a `vrrp-group` parent.
3. `..//track/priority-hold-time` selects, beneath the parent of the context node, all `priority-hold-time` elements with a `track` parent.

**Robotframework note:**

In the context of the [`Get Element Text`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html#Get%20Element%20Text) Robotframework XML library command, the XPath must be relative to the *source* node (`${output}` in your case).  Absolute XPaths such as `//priority` are not allowed there.

### See also

- [Difference between "//" and "/" in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43100052/290085)
- [What is the difference between .// and //* in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35606708/290085)
- [What is meaning of .// in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31375091/290085)

Comment: also if i use .//priority that means that it will check for priority element from the current node and not from the root node right?

Comment: @SharanyaSingh: Right.