# What does */ mean in XPath?

Tags: xml, android-layout, xpath

Why did my XPath,

```
//android.view.ViewGroup[*/android.widget.TextView[@androidXtext='Microwaves']]
```

select this node,

```
<android.view.ViewGroup androidXclickable="true" androidXcontentDescription="ucl.flex-row" androidXenabled="true" androidXfocusable="true" androidXid="@ucl.flex-row" androidXlayout_height="147px" androidXlayout_width="1059px" androidXlayout_x="11px" androidXlayout_y="913px">`
```

and not any other above or below?

Full fragment:

```
<android.view.ViewGroup androidXenabled="true" androidXlayout_height="147px" androidXlayout_width="1059px" androidXlayout_x="11px" androidXlayout_y="913px">
  <android.view.ViewGroup androidXclickable="true" androidXcontentDescription="ucl.flex-row" androidXenabled="true" androidXfocusable="true" androidXid="@ucl.flex-row" androidXlayout_height="147px" androidXlayout_width="1059px" androidXlayout_x="11px" androidXlayout_y="913px">
    <android.view.ViewGroup androidXenabled="true" androidXlayout_height="147px" androidXlayout_width="1059px" androidXlayout_x="11px" androidXlayout_y="913px">
      <android.view.ViewGroup androidXcontentDescription="ucl.flex-row.left-action.svg" androidXenabled="true" androidXid="@ucl.flex-row.left-action.svg" androidXlayout_height="63px" androidXlayout_width="63px" androidXlayout_x="53px" androidXlayout_y="955px">
        <android.view.ViewGroup androidXenabled="true" androidXlayout_height="63px" androidXlayout_width="63px" androidXlayout_x="53px" androidXlayout_y="955px">
          <android.view.ViewGroup androidXenabled="true" androidXlayout_height="0px" androidXlayout_width="0px" androidXlayout_x="53px" androidXlayout_y="955px">
            <android.view.ViewGroup androidXenabled="true" androidXlayout_height="0px" androidXlayout_width="0px" androidXlayout_x="53px" androidXlayout_y="955px"/>
          </android.view.ViewGroup>
        </android.view.ViewGroup>
      </android.view.ViewGroup>
      <android.widget.TextView androidXcontentDescription="ucl.flex-row.main.text" androidXenabled="true" androidXid="@ucl.flex-row.main.text" androidXlayout_height="53px" androidXlayout_width="891px" androidXlayout_x="137px" androidXlayout_y="960px" androidXtext="Microwaves"/>
    </android.view.ViewGroup>
  </android.view.ViewGroup>
</android.view.ViewGroup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two concepts in play here, node tests and axes:

1. `*` is equivalent to `element()`, selecting elements without regard to name.
2. The default axis is `child::`, so your predicate effectively starts with `child::element()`.

Therefore,

```
//android.view.ViewGroup[*/android.widget.TextView[@androidXtext='Microwaves']]
```

means to select all `android.view.ViewGroup` elements with a grandchild `android.widget.TextView` element that has a `androidXtext` attribute value equal to `'Microwaves'`.

When you ask specifically,

> and not any other above or below

aside from your sample XML having no other elements that meet the above criteria, note that if you were interpreting `*/` to be a wildcard that selected to all descendents, it does not.  As explained above, it only skips past children elements.  To select and test all descendent `android.widget.TextView` elements in the predicate, instead of `*/android.widget.TextView` use `descendent::android.widget.TextView` or `descendent-or-self::android.widget.TextView` (abbreviated form: `.//android.widget.TextView`).

### See also

- [What is the difference between .// and //* in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35606708/290085)
- [What is meaning of .// in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31375091/290085)
- [Difference between "//" and "/" in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43100052/290085)

Answer (score 2):

The XPath default [axis](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#axes) is `child`, so your predicate

```
[*/android.widget.TextView[@androidXtext='Microwaves']]
```

is equivalent to

```
[child::*/child::android.widget.TextView[@androidXtext='Microwaves']]
```

This predicate will select nodes with a `android.widget.TextView` grandchild and the specified attribute.